# mySQL PHP print results from multiple rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, php-5.3

This is a beginner PHP/SQL question.

Basically, I have a Database that looks like this

```
  Poem_id   |   Poem_content  |  Poem_by  |   Poem_hotscore
------------ ----------------- ----------- -----------------
     1      |  Blah Bleh<br>B.|     4     |  5342.3920349
------------ ----------------- ----------- -----------------
     7      |  Blah Bluu<br>F.|     4     |  5003.3920382
------------ ----------------- ----------- -----------------
     9      |  Blerp Bloop Foo|    34     |  4300.7281209
```

Each poem

- Has a unique `id`
- Has content
- Is written by a member with a unique `member_id`
- Has a unique `hotscore` calculated by a Cron Job using Reddit's hotscore ranking algorithm

My question is: How can I get the top three scores and display all the data from these poems?

The `PHP` code I have so far is this:

```
if ($rankerrows = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM poems ORDER BY poem_hotscore DESC")) {

    $rankerrows->execute();
    $rankerrows->store_result();


    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rankerrows)) {
        print_r($rankerrows);
    }

}
```

How exactly do I get the data from each row? I know how to do it for one row, but I'm not sure how to do it for 3 rows.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: The data is in `$row`.

Answer (score 1):

The data from each row is in `$row`, so print that, not `$rankerrows`.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rankerrows)) {
    print_r($row);
}
```

And you can add a `LIMIT 3` clause to the end of your query so it will only return the top 3 rows.

Comment: So- just to make sure I understand the concept here- everytime the program loops through the code, it goes through one row. Then, I can access a specific row's `poem_content` by using `row['poem_content']`?

Comment: Exactly. Have you read the documentation of `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`? Isn't it clear about this? being a beginner is no excuse for not reading the manual.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer didn't work but this did:

```
if ($rankerrows = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM poems ORDER BY poem_hotscore DESC LIMIT 3")) {

    $rankerrows->execute();

    $row = array();
    stmt_bind_assoc($rankerrows, $row);

    /* Store data from poems */
    $poem_id=array();
    $poem_title=array();

    $i=0;


    while ($rankerrows->fetch()) {
        $poem_id[$i]=$row['poem_id'];
        $poem_title[$i]=$row['poem_title'];
        $i++;
    }
```

Using the `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` in the other answer gave me the error that it could only be called on `mysqli_result` and not a `stmt`. Since I don't have the driver for `get_result()` and all that good stuff, this is the solution that worked